# UPDATE FOR USE ON 64-BIT- VISUAL BASIC

Tags: excel, vba, windows, 64-bit

I have this message written:

> The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems.
> Lease review and update `Declare` statements and then mark them with
> the `PtrSafe` attribute.

What should I do?

```
Public Declare Function GetUserDefaultLCID Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Public Declare Function GetSystemDefaultLCID Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Public Declare Function GetThreadLocale Lib "kernel32" () As Long
'
Public Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetLocaleInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetLocaleInfoA" (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String, ByVal cchData As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function SetLocaleInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetLocaleInfoA" (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String) As Long
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `PtrSafe` keyword befor `Function`. See below. You need to add this keyword for every function.

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetUserDefaultLCID Lib "kernel32" () As Long
```

Also read these two article from microsoft.

[Article 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ptrsafe-keyword), [Article 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/64-bit-visual-basic-for-applications-overview)

Comment: Note: *just* adding `PtrSafe` is not enough for all of those functions. All handles/pointers (eg `hwnd`) need to become `LongPtr` rather than `Long` too.

Comment: @Rory thanks for your note. I didn't read his all of functions.

Comment: @Harun24HR  `LongPtr` is needed for pointers to a → handle or → memory location. In the posted question it's the API function `PostMessage` that needs  the additional `LongPtr` arguments mentioned by @Rory: `Declare PtrSafe Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As Long`. - See [Compatibility betw. 32bit/64bit Office 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831(office.14).aspx) + [Win32API PtrSafe with 64bit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=9970)

Comment: @T.M thats true. I forgot about it.